# how to add loading spinner image to each tab in jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have loaded items in jquery tabs. When page loading, i want to show loading spinner image to each tab available inside tabs. When the count label shown, i want to remove spinner image. My code is

**Html code**:

```
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="storesa">
                <p class="tablip">
                    Store 
                    <img id="imgStore" src="ajax-loader6.gif" style="display:none;"/>  
                    <span id="store_count"/>
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    if ($('#store_count').is(':visible')) {
        $('#imgStore').hide();
    }       
});
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 1**: The following works for remote tabs (ajax loaded). You should use **beforeLoad** and **load** events to perform this.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="storesa" href="http://url-on-wich-the-ajax-request-will-be-done/">
                <p class="tablip">
                    Store 
                    <img id="imgStore" src="ajax-loader6.gif"/>  
                    <span id="store_count"/>
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#imgStore {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({

        /* Called before tab content is loaded */
        beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
            $('#imgStore').show();
            /* if ajax call to retrieve tab content failed */
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                $('#imgStore').hide();
                ui.panel.html("An error occured while loading store infos");
            });
        },

        /* Called when tab is loaded */
        load: function(event, ui) {
            $('#imgStore').hide();
            $('#store_count').html(/* your count here */);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**: @senthil-nathan : Assuming your `go_to_page()` function is loading the tabs contents i wrote this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D47yt/), hope that can help you.

Comment: You are right, this solution works for remote tab only, **beforeLoad** and **load** events are only triggered in such case. Can you add some code to show how your tab content is loaded and where you call `$("#tabs").tabs(...)` ?

Comment: It seems to be related to ie and jsfiddle. No problem using other browsers or running locally ;)

Comment: Oo that's strange, look at [this video taken on chrome](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7NtSscgvhxJdHhvMHNXUU1BS0k/edit?usp=sharing)